# Nextjs - Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "2022" Client: "2023"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

my nextjs project gives such an error in live, does anyone have any good information in local?

```
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

new year greeted with bugs

```
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "2022" Client: "2023"
```

[image]

Comment: We'll need more information. Please include all the relevant code.

Comment: @ivanatias I do not know the relevant codes, it gave such an error when I entered the new year, I added a screenshot of the error

Comment: It's a date-related issue at the new year, so the explanation is pretty obvious.  Your server and client are presumably in different timezones; the server is in 2022 and the client is in 2023, and each is generating text for the "current" year.

Comment: What @DanielBeck said!  Wait a few hours and it should clear up on its own.